# OnCollisionEnter2D doesn't restart my scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like my player to collide with an invisible collider and restart the scene right away but it seems like my script isn't working for some reason.

1. Added the tag 'Fall' on the invisible collider.
2. Added the script on the Invisible Collider Game Object.
3. Invisible collider object has Box Collider 2D Attached and is set ti: is Trigger

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class sceneRestart : MonoBehaviour
{  
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D platform)
    {
        if (platform.gameObject.tag == "Fall")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Main");
            Debug.Log("Scene Restarted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When your player collided, does `Debug.Log("Scene Restarted");` called?

Comment: Yes and I did find a problem. It was a very simple one.

Answer (score 1):

The script is attached to the invisible collider, so it needs to check if the colliding object is the player:

```cs
public class sceneRestart : MonoBehaviour
{

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Col)
    {
        if (Col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Main");
            Debug.Log("Scene Restarted");
        }
    }
```